# How to split column values in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

How do i split a single column in a DataFrame that has a string without creating more columns. And get rid of the brackets.

For example two rows looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Ala Carte':'||LA1: 53565 \nCH2: 54565', 
                'Blistex':'|Cust: 65565\nCarrier: 2565|', 
                'Dermatology':'||RTR1\n65331\n\nRTR2\n65331'})
```

And I would like for the output dataframe to look like this, where the information column is a string:

```
Customer      Information

Ala Carte     LA1: 53565 
              CH2: 54565

Blistex       Cust: 65565
              Carrier: 2565

Dermatology   RTR1: 65331
              RTR2: 65331
```

Within the same column for Information

Comment: I would be helpful in this case to show the output dictionary of your input sample data.   df.to_dict() or write the code to generate your input dataframe in the question.

Comment: This is more of a question about strings than about DataFrames, no? Could you include more of your program? A DataFrame may not be the best data structure for this.

Comment: Is the \n the only delimiter?  I think the way you are doing this is going to be complicated since the numbers you include will be taken as strings.  In your position I would first strip the brackets using str.strip(|), then I would split on the /n but this turns it into a series.  From there you can split on the colon but again this would make things into more columns at which point you can iterate through the customer to repeat for # of entries per, then you have the info string then next col you have the #s.  If you can provide more info we can see where to go.

Comment: What kind of information would you need?

Comment: @CodeMonkey The rest of your program, data, ...

Comment: Its highly sensitive so i can not share the full data, however if there are particular pieces that might be useful, i might be able to share those. Essentially, the Information column as it is right now, is an object and i cannot use the split function effectively. However, I am trying to convert the column to a string and then use regex.

Comment: @CodeMonkey Does the DataFrame creation code in your post actually run? It looks to me like the contents should be between quotes, no? Does the data get more complex than what you’ve show in the example? Is storing the attributes and data as strings like that actually alright? The data being sensitive is fine, I do think we could benefit from a description of its format.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile ive made changes to the code so that it may run, i forgot to add in the quotes as you mentioned. The contents should be a string. The data does get a little more complex in that it has more line break elements("\n") in some strings. I want to know if there is a way to make the \n actaully work as it is intended. Im positive that will solve the issue.

Comment: @CodeMonkey If you want to split a string on newlines just use `my_str.splitlines()`. Again, you may be heading for trouble with this kind of design.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile I only need to clean the data so that i can store it in an Excel file, i dont intend to do any data processing with this. Does that work on a pandas dataframe object? I need to make it so i can run it through all 2626 entries in the dataframe

Comment: @CodeMonkey Series don’t have a `splitlines()` method, however, `Series.map(str.splitlines)` should work just fine!

Comment: Also, is the number of `|` characters at the beginning and end of the string as inconsistent as in your example? We’re going to need some RegEx to get rid of those, no?

Comment: Forgot to ask: Where is this data coming from? Are you reading it from a file? There might be an easier way of doing this, at an earlier part in the program. Actually, now that I've tried it, I don't believe there is a way of doing exactly what you want. A list of strings, like in the answer by Luis Blanche, is one option. I think what we need to do now is take a step back and reconsider your program as a whole. A DataFrame might not be the appropriate data structure.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile I added a new solution to the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to just replace the '\n' to '||" as a way to separate the two different values. Combine the two columns using this def

```
def combine_with_nan(x, cols):
    combined=''
    for column in cols:
        try:
            np.isnan(x[column])
            Temp = ''
        except:
            Temp = x[column]
        combined= combined + ' || ' + Temp

    return combined 
cols=['Columns you want to merge']
practicedf = practicedf.apply(combine_with_nan, axis=1,args=(cols,)).to_frame().replace(r"\\n"," || ", regex=True)
```

Comment: I need a way to deal with white spaces in the list of columns(cols)  before combining them. Currently, I end up with blank spaces as ("|||||")

Comment: Why would you replace the line ending? What is the function for?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile The '\n' doesnt work as a line end break in a dataframe so i replaced it with a '||" to denote a new line. This data is mostly for observational purpose and i dont need to do any analysis on it. The function is to combine the columns in the list of columns that i am trying to concat. I found a way to leave the blank spaces blank and the code seems to work as intended. I appreciate all your help.

Comment: I hadn’t really thought of it, but it should be possible to make a custom function to convert the string to a DataFrame, including all the particular requirements of this data, right?

Comment: Right but that would be a less efficient way imo, so far this method has worked best for me.

Comment: Less efficient how?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it :

```py
import pandas as pd

### CREATE DATAFRAME
df = pd.DataFrame({'name' : ['Ala Carte', 'Blistex'],
                   'information': ['||LA1: 53565 \nCH2: 54565',
                                   '|Cust: 65565\nCarrier: 2565|']
                  })

### SPLIT COLUMNS INTO A LIST 
df['information'] = df['information'].apply(lambda x: x.replace("|", "").split("\n"))

### EXPLODE THE COLUMN
df.explode('information')
```

Comment: Unless some of the data we want to keep contains `'|'`, right?

Comment: Yes, I am unsure wether they were indicating columns or were actually in the strings